# Is there a possibility to access to mail from another account gmail?

Tags: php, laravel, gmail, google-workspace

I am working on PHP with Laravel and I want to create a feature for getting mails into my application.

In my company we have a GSuite plan and I wonder if it's possible to access in employees Gmail accounts for get their mails.

Gmail API ? IMAP ?

Thanks for reply

Comment: gmail api service account.  Check the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read that @DaImTo

Comment: @DaImTo No, It's not that, I want to access to employees mails without login in their gmail account. With GSuite I can administrate Gmail account of employees.

Comment: Yes and if you use a service account with domain wide delegation you will be able to access their gsuite gmail accounts.